# HTML content requested via requests is not same as that of browser

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to extract few elements from a website html using python beautifulsoup library. The problem is that the HTML from response is different from that I see on the browser. Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.nutritionix.com/brands/restaurant'

resp = requests.get(url,verify=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content)
```

I have tried using urllib library and used the browser agent parameter, but it didn't work.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The page is generated by javascript.

Try to use firebug or google dev tool. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1kXe.png)

The data you want is actually from 
https://d1gvlspmcma3iu.cloudfront.net/brands-restaurant.json.gz

Comment: Thanks for your help! And is there a way to scrape to the data from pages generated like the above? I wanted to go inside each restaurant and get the menu items list.

Comment: Yes.  The pattern  for the restaurants url is like

Comment: is like https://www.nutritionix.com/brand/NAME-OF-RESUTRANT/products/THIS-IS-THE-{ID}-YOU-GOT-FROM-THE-AJAX-CALL( aka .. from this url https://d1gvlspmcma3iu.cloudfront.net/brands-restaurant.json.gz)